# list all compute instances in a specific region gcp with python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

So, I can list my instances by zones using this API.
GET [https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{project}/zones/{zone}/instances](https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/%7Bproject%7D/zones/%7Bzone%7D/instances).
I want now to filter my instances by region. Any idea how can I do  this (using python)?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [aggregated_list()](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.instances.InstancesClient#google_cloud_compute_v1_services_instances_InstancesClient_aggregated_list), to list all your instances on your project. Filtering via region could be done on the actual code. See code below where I used regex to mimic a filter using `region` variable.

```
from typing import Dict, Iterable

from google.cloud import compute_v1
import re

def list_all_instances(
    project_id: str,
    region: str
) -> Dict[str, Iterable[compute_v1.Instance]]:

    instance_client = compute_v1.InstancesClient()
    request = {
            "project" : project_id,
            }

    agg_list = instance_client.aggregated_list(request=request)

    all_instances = {}
    print("Instances found:")
    for zone, response in agg_list:
        if response.instances:
            if re.search(f"{region}*", zone):
                all_instances[zone] = response.instances
                print(f" {zone}:")
                for instance in response.instances:
                    print(f" - {instance.name} ({instance.machine_type})")
    return all_instances

list_all_instances(project_id="your-project-id",region="us-central1") #used us-central1 for testing
```

NOTE: Code above is from [this code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-compute/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/instances/list_all.py). I just modified it to apply the filtering above.

Actual instances on my GCP account:

[image]

Result from code above (only zones with prefix us-central1 were displayed):

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked ! ( I was using the same method but didn't find the right rex)

Comment: @RouaKhenissi That is good to hear. You can accept the answer so the question will be marked as solved! See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)